# Module augmentation error :'x' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I'm somewhat new to this. So excuse me if I get this wrong.
What i'm trying to do this to define a method on the protractor ElementFinder class prototype.

I'm following the syntax in the merged pull request here.https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6213

```
> 1 import { ElementFinder} from "protractor";
> 2 
> 3 declare module "protractor" {
> 4   interface ElementFinder {
> 5        doSomething(): void;
> 6    } }
> 7
> 8
> 9  ElementFinder.prototype.doSomething = function (): void {
> 10    console.log(""); 
> 11 };
```

I'm getting this error on line 9

> [ts] 'ElementFinder' only refers to a type, but is being used as a
>   value here.

What am I doing wrong here? The only thing that is different in the example is that I'm using module from npm rather than one defined in the my package.Is it not possible to augment modules this way?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `ElementFinder` is typed as an `interface` and not a `class`.  There seems to be no exported object named `ElementFinder` you can reference to get its prototype.  Does protractor give you an `ElementFinder` constructor at runtime?  If so, you can type it like this:

```
type Constructor<T> = {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
    readonly prototype: T;
}
declare module "protractor" {
  interface ElementFinder {
    doSomething(): void;
  }
  export const ElementFinder: Constructor<ElementFinder>;
}
```

This *should* fix the type error, but make sure that there actually is an `ElementFinder` constructor at runtime, or this will just explode when you run it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Object3D'.` (where Object3D is the class name I'm trying to extend) on your `export const` line.

Comment: I would need to see a [mcve] of your issue before I could suggest anything.  On the face of it, this question and its answer don't apply to your case because the compiler already sees a variable named `Object3D` in scope; the above question and answer have the issue that the compiler didn't have any such variable.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, turned out to be https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18877 - i got here as the error I was seeing before trying `export const` was the same as OP - even though the cause in my case was a compiler bug :(